# The parenthesis get removed from Sendkey method whenever we pass a string containing the same. Any suggestion how to overcome this?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, sendkeys

```
d1.findElementById("originlocation").sendKeys("Indira Gandhi Airport(DEL) near Delhi in India");
```

When text gets entered into the textbox, the parenthesis gets removed completely.
(DEL) CHANGES TO DEL, but what we want is (DEL) AS IT IS.

Comment: Weird.  I tested with a test script of mine and I could write parenthesis to an input text element.  Check the HTML element if any filtering is configured or any JS script that remove parenthesis or whatever that could remove parenthesis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my problem got resolved by using below code:

```
 List<WebElement> items = d1.findElements(By.xpath("html/body/ul[1]/li/a"));
               // look for item on list that contains Melbourne (MEL)
               for(int i= 0; i <items.size();i++){
               if(items.get(i).getText().contains("Indira Gandhi Airport(DEL)")){
               items.get(i).click();
               break; 
               }}
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems to be reproducible in firefox.. so as a workaround can u try with:

```
d1.findElementById("originlocation").sendKeys("Indira Gandhi Airport(DEL) near Delhi in India"
    .replace("(", Keys.chord(Keys.SHIFT, "9"))
    .replace(")", Keys.chord(Keys.SHIFT, "0")));
```

Comment: hi vivek, this gets inputted when i tried your code....Indira Gandhi AirportDEL near Delhi in India

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried encasing in single quotes instead of double-qoutes?
Maybe 
`d1.findElementById("originlocation").sendKeys('Indira Gandhi Airport(DEL) near Delhi in India');`

would work?

Just a suggestion.  Another suggestion since you're putting text into a text field or textarea element, is to set the value of the element with the text as opposed to using sendKeys.

Comment: hi Adam, i need to confirm do u want me to put single quotes instead of double quotes in the sendkeys method?

Comment: @Harsh Yes, first try single quotes, although I'm not sure 100% that it will work. Next, try setting the value of the element with id "originlocation" to contain your text string 'Indira Gandhi Airport...'